# How can I convert linq object to asp.net object..?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Code:

```
Domain ob = new Domain();

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Domain ob)
{
    try
    {
        //// TODO: Add insert logic here
        FirstTestDataContext db = new FirstTestDataContext();

        tblSample ord = new tblSample();
        ord = ob;
        db.tblSamples.InsertOnSubmit(ord);

        db.SubmitChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here I am getting an error like this

Cannot implicitly convert type 'mvcInsertLinqForms.Models.Domain' to 'mvcInsertLinqForms.tblSample'

Comment: What do you *expect* the `ord = ob;` statement to do? And why are you creating a new `tblSample` for no reason?

Comment: The assignment ord = ob has left side of type "tblSample" while right side of type Domain. Are they assignable types?

Comment: @Jon The expectation is probably obvious, the statement should convert one object into the other. It is the language/tech which is too constrained to understand and autoimplement such expectation :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Right now you have said that an apple is an orange which obviously isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign `ord` to `ob` because they are not of the same type. You seem to be attempting to map the view model (`ob`) to your domain model (`tblSample`). You could do this by setting the corresponding properties of the domain model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Domain ob)
{
    try
    {
        tblSample ord = new tblSample();
        // now map the domain model properties from the 
        // view model properties which is passed as action
        // argument:
        ord.Prop1 = ob.Prop1;
        ord.Prop2 = ob.Prop2;
        ...

        FirstTestDataContext db = new FirstTestDataContext();
        db.tblSamples.InsertOnSubmit(ord);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and to avoid doing this mapping manually you could use a tool such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) which could help you mapping back and forth between your view models and your domain models.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult (Domain model) // or (FormCollection form), use form.get("phone")
{
//---
return View();
}
```